# What is a wrapper for a stored procedure in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

What is the definition of a wrapper for a stored procedure in sql server?

Comment: It could mean a few different things.  Do you have a sentence that uses wrapper in the context you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given us much to go off of, but I suspect you are talking about a C# wrapper for the stored proc.  This just allows you to have a method that calls the stored proc from code.  For example if you had a stored proc called `DeleteUser`  you could make a .NET wrapper for like so:

```
private void DeleteUser(int UserId)
{
   //Call your stored proc from here
}
```